# can't view right side of website on mobile device

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I'm unable to view the right side of my website on a mobile device. This is the basic coding for the html and container style. The problem lies within here somewhere but I can't figure it out. I've tried several options but no luck. Please help.

```
    html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
max-width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #container {
background-color: #000;
height: 1054px;
width: 1400px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: -20px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it, I just removed the max-width and overflow-x:hidden from the html body tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

set width to 100% on #container. Delete other widths and heights.

Comment: Still unable to view full page on mobile device.

Comment: Do I need to remove the height and width from all divs? I tried, but it makes everything uneven.